# Grep between patterns on separate lines or single line

Tags: grep, wildcards

So what I would need is for grep to match only the text in between (and including) my match pattern.

So something like this (don't mind the text, it's just some garble :D):

```
asdgfasd gasd gdas g This will be this one day ksjadnbalsdkbgas asd gasdg 
asdgasdgasdg dasg dasg dasg This will be this next day adf gdsf gdsf sdfh dsfhdfsh
asdf asdf asd fesf dsfasd f This will won' not this day asdgadsgaseg as dvf as d vfa se v asd
dasfasdfdas fase fasdfasefase fasdf This not what shoes day asdjbna;sdgbva;sdkbcvd;lasb ;lkbasi hasdli glais g
```

So what I want is something like this:
`cat theabovetext|grep -E "^This * day$"`
To output this:

```
This will be this one day
This will be this next day
This will won' not this day
This not what shoes day
```

So basically I want to ONLY get the text in between This and Day (including This and day) regardless of how many characters there are in between, and regardless of how many characters there are before This and after Day.
Also this needs to work even if the input is all on a single line, so this:

`asdgfasd gasd gdas g This will be this one day ksjadnbalsdkbgas asd gasdg asdgasdgasdg dasg dasg dasg This will be this next day adf gdsf gdsf sdfh dsfhdfsh asdf asdf asd fesf dsfasd f This will won' not this day asdgadsgaseg as dvf as d vfa se v asd dasfasdfdas fase fasdfasefase fasdf This not what shoes day asdjbna;sdgbva;sdkbcvd;lasb ;lkbasi hasdli glais g`

Has to output this:

`This will be this one day This will be this next day This will won' not this day This not what shoes day`

N.B. the output here is still on a single line.

Comment: What version of `grep` are you looking to use?  GNU with perl style regex will can do it, otherwise are you open to non-`grep` solutions?

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.20, but if it's awk or sed, I can work with those as well

Comment: @superme I've attempted to emphasise important parts of your question. Feel free to re-edit if I have misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want lines to be processed separately (your first example) but for multiple matches per line to be output on a single line (as in your second example), then I don't think that's possible with `grep` alone.

However using the same `This.*?day` non-greedy match in perl itself you can do

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /This.*?day/g' theabovetext1
This will be this one day
This will be this next day
This will won' not this day
This not what shoes day
```

while for the single-line input

```
$ perl -lne 'print join " ", /This.*?day/g' theabovetext2
This will be this one day This will be this next day This will won' not this day This not what shoes day
```

Answer (score 5):

With GNU `grep` you could do the following:

```
grep -o 'This.*day' theabovetext
```

(note that you don't need `cat` since `grep` knows how to read files)

The `-o` flag says to show only the parts of the line that match the pattern.

I suspect other versions of `grep` support this flag as well, but it's not in POSIX, so it's not portable necessarily.

Comment: `[me@there ~]$ grep -o 'This.*day' theabovetext
This will be this one day ksjadnbalsdkbgas asd gasdg asdgasdgasdg dasg dasg dasg This will be this next day adf gdsf gdsf sdfh dsfhdfsh asdf asdf asd fesf dsfasd f This will won' not this day asdgadsgaseg as dvf as d vfa se v asd dasfasdfdas fase fasdfasefase fasdf This not what shoes day`
it only removes the first part and the last part of the gibberish it doesn't remove it in between matches

Comment: You can use PCRE mode so that the quantifier can be made non-greedy `grep -oP 'This.*?day' theabovetext` however this will place each match on a separate line in both cases

Comment: @steeldriver that worked, thanks! I can't select your comment as the right answer though. One thing I'd like to know though: how come with `'This.*day'` it doesn't match it, but adding the `?` matches it?

Comment: @superme I didn't post it as an answer because I don't believe it satisfies your requirement that *"the output here is still on a single line"* for the case where the input is on a single line

Comment: Oh sorry about that, the output can be of any format, as long as it's the selected text, I can modify it afterwards, my bad for not mentioning it, sorry :), so how come the extra `?` helped?

Comment: @superme it modifies the `*` to make it *non-greedy* - see for example [Perl regex tutorial: non-greedy expressions](https://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials-power-tips/ultraedit/non-greedy-perl-regex.html)

Comment: thanks, if you put this as a answer I'll select it

Answer (score 0):

Eric Renouf's response does most of the work. And steeldriver's comment cuts out the extra text within a given line by making it non-greedy.

So it seems like:  `grep -oP 'This.*?day' theabovetext` does everything you want except the output is on multiple lines.

To put the output on one line you could do `grep -oP 'This.*?day' theabovetext | tr '\n' ' '`. This addition simply replaces newline breaks with spaces*

*This will replace all output newlines with spaces. So if your initial input is line separated, these newline breaks will be lost.